# Why "no" rather than "not" in "Life is no Nintendo game"?

Tags: differences, negation, no-not

I've just seen this sentence on the internet...

> You don't get another chance. Life is **no** Nintendo game.
> — [Love the Way You Lie](https://genius.com/Eminem-love-the-way-you-lie-lyrics)

If I had to say something like that, I would say "Life is not a Nintendo game."

Why did he say "**no**"? What is more correct? and what is the difference?

Comment: See also http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7744/is-it-is-no-calculus-correct-grammar

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Does not make changes" or "makes no changes"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61326/does-not-make-changes-or-makes-no-changes)

Comment: Also see [What is the difference between no and not?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64369), and [When to use no good, when to use not good](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64510),   and [Is it not that big a deal vs no big deal](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69313),   and [There is no rule vs there isn't rule](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9427),   and [Rules for no and not](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50066),  besides aforementioned [Does not make changes or makes no changes](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61326),

Comment: possible duplicate of ["There is no rule" vs. "there isn't rule"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9427/there-is-no-rule-vs-there-isnt-rule)

Answer (score 6):

This is a common idiom that is subtly different from the regular use of *no* and *not*. It’s used to make a comparison against an *ideal* or *standard* thing, and is often used to compare skills:

> **He’s no “king of comedy”**, but Dane Cook can make people laugh.
>
> Michael Bublé is a pretty good singer, but **he’s no Frank Sinatra.**

Your example sentence is saying you don’t get another chance because life is not a Nintendo game—though *ideally* it would be, because everybody wants a second chance at life.

This is also used with negative descriptions to cast someone in a positive light. “She’s no fool” means “she’s actually very wise/savvy”. Occasionally you also see it used in a rhetorical way, to give the reader a negative expectation but “surprise” them with a positive description:

> He’s no Nikola Tesla—he’s even smarter than that!

Answer (score 2):

Neither is more correct. They both mean the same thing, however using "no" gives it more intriguing feel, and "not a" gives a cold definite statement.

Answer (score 1):

When a noun has an non-gradable meaning (it is either something or it is not) we cannot use *"no" + noun*.

> A potato is **not a** fruit. 
> <strike>A potato is no fruit</strike>.

When a noun has a gradable meaning, *"no" + noun* means the same as *"not a/an" + noun*:

> It's **no** secret that we are interested. (=It's not a secret. *A
>   secret is gradable. Something can be more of a secret than something
>   else.*)

In the context you have provided I suppose that one can give only an opinion on how a Nintendo game, metaphorically speaking, is, so:

> You don't get another chance. Life is **not a** Nintendo game.

*and*

> You don't get another chance. Life is **no** Nintendo game.

are both correct.

<sub>Reference: English Grammar Today (Cambridge)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

He is no Albert Einstein - In this case Albert Einstein becomes a type of person.
( Smart people can be compared to Albert Einstein. He is not among those people)

He is not Albert Einstein - In this case we are talking about Albert Einstein the person.
( He is John Smith, not Albert Einstein )